# non-singular solution of first order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Good day!

Problem: $$u_{t}+u^{2}u_{x}=0,$$
$$u(x,0)=\cos x.$$

Solution: $$u(x,t)=\cos (x-u^{2}t).$$

Need to find maximum t such  the non-singular solution exists on all $[0,t).$ Вut I don't know where the singularities will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the inplicit function theorem to your
relation $u-\cos(x-u^2 t)=0$ to see where it defines $u$
as a function of $(x,t)$. It looks (if I have not made a mistake)
as though the $u$-partial derivative of the relation is zero
at $(x,t,u)$ when $\displaystyle t = \frac{1}{2u\sqrt{1-u^2}} = \frac{1}{\sin(2x_0)}$, where $x_0$ is the point on the $x$ axis where the characteristic
through $(x,t)$ begins. This is minimum when the sine is maximum, so $t=1$.
I won't fill in all details because you labeled it homework, but you might sketch the characteristics to see what is happening.

Comment: I didn't guess to use Implicit function theorem.Thank you very much :^)